# Fiddlercore x-replywithfile over 2gb

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

So I have an application that is caching local files with some code like this:

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
{
    if (oS.url.StartsWith("foo.com/"))
    {
        oS.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
        oS.oFlags["x-replywithfile"] = Path.GetFullPath(oS.url.Replace("foo.com/", "serve/"));
    }
}
```

This works fine for any files < 2GB. Above 2GB I get the error:

```
Fiddler - The requested file could not be read. The file is too long. This operation is currently limited to supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size.
```

I'm assuming internally Fiddler is using something like `File.ReadAllBytes` which is limited to 2gb because of maximum size of int. As far as I can tell there's no source code for FiddlerCore to open it up and change this... anyone know how to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool scenario.

Yes, unfortunately the .NET Framework inherently limits all objects to a 2GB size, and as a consequence earlier versions of the AutoResponder *could not* return responses over 2gb. **Update:** Fiddler version 2.4.9.4 and later automatically detect huge files; any `X-ReplyWithFile` body over 262 megabytes (`fiddler.memory.DropIfOver` preference) will be streamed from the client and not stored in memory.

You *could* use Fiddler to return a `HTTP/307` redirect to a different webserver and host the huge file there.

Your event handler could also directly stream the bytes of the file to the client in chunks (without using the x-replywithfile feature) using the `oSession.oRequest.pipeClient.Send` method, but this would involve a significant amount of code.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up running a local IIS instance and doing oS.url = "localhost/largefile.mp4"; I'm trying to cache video files on the local PC, but I found with even < 2gb videos the seek/buffering functionality of my video player didn't work correctly. I was hoping to not have to use a local web server, if I have some extra time I'll see about chunking it to see if that helps with my seeking/size problem.